# Match object from map and get its records

Tags: apex, map

I have a logic issue with the next code which I cannot manage to solve.
I will receive a `Map<String, List<Sobject>> recordsMap` and I need to match the String which will be the object name and get the List and match it with the mapping fields

```
public List<SubsExtendedInfo> generateWrapperInfo (Map<String, List<Sobject>> recordsMap){
        //object Name >> records

        Map<String, SubscriberMapping__c> mappingFieldsMap = SubscriberMapping__c.getAll();

        // This mappingFieldsMap has the name of the object with the mapping fields
        // The obj name should match with the map string and then by its name get the equivalent mapping fields List<Sobject> - mappingFieldsMap

       // mappingFieldsMap.get(Key).SF_Object_API_Name__c
       // This is the object name field from the mappingFieldsMap
        return null;
}
```

I cannot figure out how to do it, could anyone help me?

> ***SubscriberMapping__c Structure***
>
> Product Field Name  ||  FieldName__c
>
> Object API Name     || SF_Object_API_Name__c
>
> SF_Field_API_Name   || SF_Field_API_Name__c
>
> ***SubscriberMapping__c Values***
>
> **Name    ||  Product Field Name  ||  Object API Name  ||     SF_Field_API_Name**
>
> Contact-Email  ||      Email  ||      Contact   ||    Email
>
> Contact-First Name  ||    First Name  ||    Contact  ||   FirstName

And the Map will the String for the obj name and List is the object with its fields and values, the fields are the same as SF_Field_API_Name in the custom setting.

So I should match the obj name and then the field names to get its values.

Comment: can you post a picture of custom settings and the values of recordsMap

Comment: I have added all the data I have, the custom setting structure and 2 rows as example of what it has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I can understand your requirement correctly, here will be the code.

```
public List<SubsExtendedInfo> generateWrapperInfo (Map<String, List<Sobject>> recordsMap){

Map<String, SubscriberMapping__c> mappingFieldsMap = SubscriberMapping__c.getAll();

    for(String str:mappingFieldsMap.keyset())
    {
        SubscriberMapping__c mc = SubscriberMapping__c.getValues(str);

        //retrieve values based on key
        String objectAPIName = mc.get('Object API Name');
        String strSF_Field_API_Name = mc.get('SF_Field_API_Name');

        //compare with the values passed as argument in this method.
        if(recordsMap.containsKey(objectAPIName))
        {
            //get the list of SObject
            List<Sobject> lst = recordsMap.get(objectAPIName);

            //loop through the list
            for(Sobject sobj:lst)
            {
                //print the values from SObject where API name will from custom settings.
                System.debug('print the values=' + sobj.get(strSF_Field_API_Name))

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes the approach works for me to understand how to iterate over the method args. Thank you